# Duplicating Data in My SQL for multiple tables at once

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a react app using MySQL for the database. One of the user has requested the ability to duplicate data to speed up the process when we have multiple reports for 1 client. I have 4 associated tables. Clients - Color Charts - Accounts - Holdings. This drills down like a typical folder browers, a client can have any number of color charts, color charts have any number of accounts, accounts have any number of holdings. Accounts and holdings both maintain the id_cc (color chart id).

She wants to duplicate color charts so when we run a report 3-6 months later we can duplicate the old and tweak it rather than building a new one from scratch or editing the old one and losing our version history.

Using the insert query below I am able to easily duplicate the accounts to a new color chart, but what im not sure how to do is duplicate the holdings.

```
insert into accounts 
    (id_cc, name, type, inside_outside, amount, notes)
select 
    '114', name, type, inside_outside, amount, notes
From 
    accounts
where 
    id_cc = 10;
```

The problem is the holdings are associated with specific accounts so I cant just insert them in the same fashion. The holdings table is...

```
id int AI PK 
id_acc int 
id_cc int 
type varchar(45) 
name varchar(45) 
amount int
```

*id_acc is referencing the AI ID of the accounts table.

Any advise on how to approach this duplication of data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't easily do this if you duplicate the accounts in one query. You need to loop over all the accounts one at a time. Duplicate it, get the new `id_acc` for that, then duplicate all the old accounts holdings to the new account.

Comment: @Barmar Do you have an example of how I would write that loop in MySQL? I've only built loops in react so far so I'm not sure what that loop would look like.

Comment: You'd have to do it in a stored procedure. You use a cursor to iterate over the results of a query. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Comment: I'm not following what is your business requirement here, but "duplicating data" is always a really, really bad idea. If you have slowly-changing 'static' information, and you're keeping "version history", I suspect what you want is to include an 'effective date' (range). 'Tweaking' a version then means putting an expiry date on the old version, bringing forward (inserting) a new version which might well be a tweaked copy of the now-expired.

Comment: ... 'static' there in scare quotes, because no data is truly static; it's a question of how frequently changing.